# What logger to use for Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions

Firebase recommends in [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) to use their cloud functions logger SDK. Does anyone recommend to use another logger such as Winston instead?

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");
  functions.logger.log("Hello from info");
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use directly [Cloud Logging library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) as it gives more customization if needed. ([Firebase logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#custom-logs) relies on it)

If you prefer Winston you have an implementation for Google Cloud. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-winston-quickstart

I would choose one or another depending on "portability". If you plan to stick with Firebase/Google Cloud I will go for Cloud Logging as it will work also with other Google services (ex. Cloud Run). If not, Winston is almost and standard.

Comment: Awesome! Would you recommend to stick with Google Cloud, or use an external tool like Datadog?

Comment: There is no a straightforward answer. Datadog is a very complete observability platform, is no only about logging. If you just want to monitor logs for a bunch of apps deployed on google cloud just use the google cloud services. It is more convenient and you can integrate with a couple of clicks.